# An error occurred while trying to restore packages: 'Dapper' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Data.SqlClient'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, nuget, dapper

I am trying to run an old system on Visual Studio 2012. When I try to restore the packages using package manager console I got this error.

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages:
> 'Dapper' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Data.SqlClient'

[image]

Then I tried to install Dapper 1.50, as suggested by another question and got the following error kept showing up.

> NuGet\Install-Package : 'Dapper' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Data.SqlClient'.
> At line:1 char:1
> NuGet\Install-Package Dapper -Version 1.50.5
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Then I tried uninstalling dapper and got the following error.

> NuGet\uninstall-Package : Unable to find package 'Dapper'.
> At line:1 char:1
> NuGet\uninstall-Package Dapper
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Uninstall-Package], InvalidOperationException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.UninstallPackageCommand

Is there any steps I can follow to fix these issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dapper 1.50.5 is ancient (2018) and includes a `System.Data.SqlClient` dependency. In short: *don't use the ancient thing*; "current" is 2.1.35 at the time of writing, and does *not* have any such dependency. So... use that. This still supports down to .NET Framework 4.6.1. If you need something earlier than that... [good luck](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/01/net-core-net-5-exodus-of-net-framework.html)!